# Python server ipv6 UDP program

Tags: udp, server, ipv6

```
 import socket
 import sys
 HOST = 'fe80:ba27:ebff:fed4:5687'
 PORT = 6848
 try :
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print 'Socket created'
 except socket.error, msg :
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
```

## Bind socket to local host and port

```
 try:
 s.bind((HOST,PORT))
 except socket.error , msg:
       print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
       sys.exit()
 print 'Socket bind complete'
```

## now keep talking with the client

```
 while 1:
# receive data from client (data, addr)
d = s.recvfrom(1024)
data = d[0]
addr = d[1]

if not data: 
    break

reply =  data

s.sendto(reply , addr)
print 'Message[' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]) + '] - ' + data.strip()

s.close()
```

This code was developed according IPv4 UDP server. After running this program I am getting the following error.

**Bind failed. Error Code : -3 Message Temporary failure in name resolution
-bash: Bind: command not found**

I have searched in google but i am unable to figure out what was the error.
Can someone help me where was wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You are setting `HOST` to a link-local address without the scope on the end. I think you probably want to use a routable IPv6 address instead of the link-local address which can't be routed off the link.

Comment: How to get IPv6 routable address ?

Comment: Routable IPv6 addresses are assigned by your ISP.

Comment: This is not even a valid IPv6 address. The second colon is missing after `fe80:`.

Comment: Which language is that? You didn't tag your question with a language. The code looks like Python code with the indentation messed up, but the error message indicate that it is bash. If it is Python code, then you need to fix the indentation. Indentation is significant in Python, so without correct indentation we cannot know what the code does.